# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException displaying error in the console using Selenium and AppiumDriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, targetinvocationexception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: The session identified by cf4e113d-a5e7-42f1-a1a3-fa0a90049d63 is not known
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'puranams-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:183e:1d20:c1d1:7a1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by cf4e113d-a5e7-42f1-a1a3-fa0a90049d63 is not known
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:264)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:258)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'puranams-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:183e:1d20:c1d1:7a1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:225)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:338)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:89)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:99)
    at Tenmates_Hybride_Base.capabilities(Tenmates_Hybride_Base.java:45)
    at Hybride_Signup_Flow.main(Hybride_Signup_Flow.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:193)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: The session identified by cf4e113d-a5e7-42f1-a1a3-fa0a90049d63 is not known
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'puranams-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:183e:1d20:c1d1:7a1%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '11.5', java.version: '16.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: AppiumDriver
remote stacktrace: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: The session identified by cf4e113d-a5e7-42f1-a1a3-fa0a90049d63 is not known
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:54)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:264)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:258)
    at io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:435)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:250)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:611)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:466)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a log here, we need to know what you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your base exception is...

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

[InvocationTargetException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor. It is an extra level of abstraction by calling the method with reflection. The reflection layer wraps any exception in an `InvocationTargetException`. The "target exception" that is provided at construction time and accessed via the [`getTargetException()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#getTargetException--) method is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the [`Throwable.getCause()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) method, as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."

### Solution

The best approach would be to **unwrap** the cause within the `InvocationTargetException` to get the the original exception.

```
try {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // the real cause
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        
} catch (Exception e) {
        // generic exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

### Best Practice

As per the best practices follow the below guidelines:

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current _chrome=96.0.4664.45. (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).